# Update column with SUM from another table, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I try to update my `users` `points` based on a `SUM` from another table.

```
UPDATE users u
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(user_score_for_answer) as total
    FROM answer_histories
    GROUP BY user_id, total
) a ON users.id = a.user_id
SET U.points = a.total
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, the syntax looks like:

```
UPDATE users u
    SET points = a.total
FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(user_score_for_answer) as total
      FROM answer_histories
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) a 
WHERE u.id = a.user_id;
```

Comment: A good practice in SQL language is avoiding aggregate functions (such as SUM, COUNT, MAX, etc.) in the 'GROUP BY' clause, so 'total' is unnecessary in this example, i.e. 'GROUP BY user_id' is enough to achieve what you want. For more information, please have a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is great, just getting small error - "aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY" which can be fixed by simply removing total from GROUP BY.

*(I could not put this in comment due to insufficient reputation).